# Share @ModelAttribute between methods

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I'm new on spring and I have this controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("mediaJson")
@Transactional(value=CLIENT_TRANSACTION_MANAGER, readOnly=true)
public String getPlayerMedia(@PathVariable String playerHash, @PathVariable String mediaId) throws ServiceException, JsonProcessingException {
    PlayerController playerController = new PlayerController();
    playerController = authenticationService.authenticatePlayerHash(playerHash);
    PlayerMediaDTO media = playerService.getPlayerMedia(playerController, mediaId, null, null, null);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(media);
    return json;
}

@ModelAttribute("attrs")
public ViewAttributes getProxyPath(@ModelAttribute("mediaJson") String jsonString) {
    ViewAttributes attr = new ViewAttributes();
    attr.setProxy(proxy);
    attr.setDescription(jsonString);
    return attr;
}
//View 
@RequestMapping(value="/index/{playerHash}/{mediaId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadMediaJson(@PathVariable String playerHash, @PathVariable String mediaId, ModelMap model) {
    return "index";
}
```

Notice that I'd like to access the mediaJson attribute to the attrs Attribute to populate it. How can I do that?
I've tried here but it seems that it works only if I put a debug breakpoint on the setDescription line ( probably because of sync ).

Can anyone help me with it?